# Custom theme, contact form 7 & fast secure form doesn't work

Tags: theme-development, functions, jquery, plugin-contact-form-7

I have problems with the plugins CF 7 & FSF. When I paste the code

```
[si-contact-form form='1']
```

for FSF I get the result of the code "[si-c..." itself when I load the page instead of a form. I have built a custom theme and doesnt have any other plugins installed. The same thing happens when I try to use CF 7 and the embedded code provided by that plugin.

I have several javascripts enqued in functions.php.

I have included wp_head() & wp_footer() in the file so I know that's not the problem.

This is how my functions.php file looks like, am I missing something here?

```
<?php

function add_js()  
{  
        // Register Jquery & UI
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
      wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
        wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js' );


    // Register the scripts for theme
        wp_register_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr-2.0.6.custom.js', true);
        wp_register_script( 'modernizr-pointerevents', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr-pointerevents.min.js', true);   
        wp_register_script( 'easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js', array('jquery'), true);  
        wp_register_script( 'localscroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js', array('jquery'), true);  
        wp_register_script( 'scrollto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js', array('jquery'), true);
        wp_register_script( 'backstretch', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js', array('jquery'), true); 
        wp_register_script( 'mousewheel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js', array('jquery'), true);   
        wp_register_script( 'customScrollbar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js', array('jquery'), true);  
        wp_register_script( 'functions', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array('jquery'), true);    


    // Enque the scripts 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr' ); 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr-pointerevents' ); 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'easing' ); 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'localscroll' ); 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'scrollto' ); 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'backstretch' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mousewheel' ); 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'customScrollbar' );  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'functions' );  
}  

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js' );


?>
```

I had to deregister jquery and register it manually in order to get the scripts depending on jquery to work. Could this be the error that make the plugins stop working?

I have tested with other plugins, such as compress of js & css and those works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution myself,

It had something to do with my code echoing out

```
$content = $page->post_content
... echo $content;...
```

I changed this to

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
... echo $content;...
```

And now it works!

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405974/using-get-pages-in-wordpress-is-stripping-out-my-p-tags